# Chrome save CSS, load on site load

Tags: css, google-chrome

Sometimes on sites l like to edit the CSS in order to make the site prettier, less cluttered, whatever.

l want this CSS to be saved so that every time I go to that site, it's the way l like it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look into writing a Greasemonkey script - that's what they were meant for.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Doesn't that have to be on the site itself?

Comment: Nope! Greasemonkey scripts are loaded from your local browser environment, and the get dynamically injected into the site's script!

Comment: Actually I would agree with Vishnu M.'s answer instead of Greasemonkey - I forgot about Stylish, and it's probably a more specialized tool for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Chrome extension called [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). It works quite well and you can share and download styles you and others have built for websites.

Comment: Testing now, but, why does it need my broswer history?

Comment: This works well, but doesn't have the ease-of-use of Chrome's built-in style editing.

Comment: Additionally, I can't style something w/o an id or class.